# Cannot move vertices

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view

Cannot move vertices up or down in z axis?[image]

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: Check that your object isn't Z scaled to 0 in its transform matrix.. (Ctrl-A, apply scale)

Comment: It was scaled in Z ..it works